# Настройка urlrewrite.php в Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, url, чпу, breadcrumbs

На сайте существует физический раздел courses в котором используется компонент каталог. Соответственно сам битрикс разбивает их на различные разделы например: /courses/psychology/ и просто загружает данные из раздела инфоблока и элементы данного раздела, при этом выставляя нормальные хлебные крошки. Хочу добавить комплексную страницу чтобы url получался /courses/psychology/complex/. Сейчас имею такой код:

```
137 =>
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/courses/psychology/complex/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/courses/complex.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
```

и проблема состоит в том что условие не отрабатывает и я получаю ошибку **Элемент не найден**. Как можно решить подобнуюп проблему чтобы был ЧПУ, вызывался мой файл, и можно было без проблем подключить хлебные крошки во все это?

Comment: если правильно понял то нужно добавить ваше правило `'CONDITION' => '#^/courses/psychology/complex/#',` выше правила о разделе #^/courses/.. в файле urlrewrite.php (тогда оно выполнится раньше и ниже не пойдёт искать другие правила).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы было простое: завести то же правило через админку битрикса. Он сам присвоил ему нужный номер и соответственно расположил в нужном месте т.е. выше раздела /courses/.